# How to use cloud shell to secure ssh access to Azure VMs?

Tags: azure, security, ssh

Is it possible to ssh to Azure VMs using cloud shell ONLY in order to enhance security?
So that I can disable public access to 22 port.

Answer (score 0):

### No you can't do that.  The cloud shell could have a different public ip address every time you use it, so you won't be able to setup a Network Security Group to allow cloud shell to ssh to your VM.   The Azure Bastion service does what you're looking for, but is only available in a subset of regions.

Comment: Sorry for the late respond. Thank you so much for your reply. It works well!